# frustum for frustum culling isn't created proper

Tags: java, frustum

**Introduction:**

I'm trying to implement frustum culling and for that I created a projectionViewMatrix and then translate the vectors with the matrix. However some of the vectors seem to be incorrectly calculated. (*Coordinate system: +x to the right, +y up and +z out of the screen*)

**Code:**

```
public static void updateFrustum(Camera camera) {
    Vector3f[] points = calculateFrustumVertices(camera);
    plane[0].setPlane(points[1], points[0], points[2]);
    plane[1].setPlane(points[4], points[5], points[7]);
    plane[2].setPlane(points[0], points[4], points[3]);
    plane[3].setPlane(points[5], points[1], points[6]);
    plane[4].setPlane(points[2], points[3], points[6]);
    plane[5].setPlane(points[4], points[0], points[1]);
}

private static Vector3f[] calculateFrustumVertices(Camera camera) {
    // projectionMatrix was saved once at the beginning
    Matrix4f inverseProjView = Matrix4f.mul(projectionMatrix, Maths.createViewMatrix(camera), null);
    inverseProjView.invert();
    Vector3f[] points = new Vector3f[8];
    Vector4f vertex = new Vector4f();
    vertex.w = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        vertex.x = clipCube[i].x;
        vertex.y = clipCube[i].y;
        vertex.z = clipCube[i].z;
        Matrix4f.transform(inverseProjView, vertex, vertex);
        vertex.x /= vertex.w;
        vertex.y /= vertex.w;
        vertex.z /= vertex.w;
        vertex.w /= vertex.w;
        points[i] = new Vector3f(vertex);
    }
    return points;
}

static Matrix4f viewMatrix = new Matrix4f();
public static Matrix4f createViewMatrix(Camera camera) {
    viewMatrix.setIdentity();
    Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(camera.getPitch()), Maths.xRotation, viewMatrix, viewMatrix);
    Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(camera.getYaw()), Maths.yRotation, viewMatrix, viewMatrix);
    Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(camera.getRoll()), Maths.zRotation, viewMatrix, viewMatrix);
    Maths.reusableVector = camera.getPosition();
    Maths.reusableVector2.set(-Maths.reusableVector.x, -Maths.reusableVector.y, -Maths.reusableVector.z);
    Matrix4f.translate(Maths.reusableVector2, viewMatrix, viewMatrix);
    return viewMatrix;
}
```

**Example output:**

For this I stand at the origin `(0, 0, 0)` and look in the direction of +z. My near plane is `0.001`, my far plane is `1000` and the FOV is `60°`. The result is (printed out each point in the for-loop in `calculateFrustumVertices()`):

- `points[0] = (0, 0, 0)`
- `points[1] = (0, 0, 0)`
- `points[2] = (0, 0, 0)`
- `points[3] = (0, 0, 0)`
- `points[4] = (1127, -591, 1110)`
- `points[5] = (-1114, -591, 1110)`
- `points[6] = (-1114, 668, 1110)`
- `points[7] = (1127, 668, 1110)`

Note that the first four points aren't exactly the same but due to the really small near plane distance (0.001) they almost are equal to zero. I left away the decimal places (because they're irreevant).

**Problem:**

Roughly the shape of the frustum is correct. But in my opinion the points are a bit wrong.

1. If the origin is at `(0, 0, 0)` shouldn't the coordinates be 
   symetric? So for example if the x-value of point 4 and 7 is equal to 1127, 
   then shouldn't the value of point 5 and 6 be eqal to -1127? (same for y and z).
2. ([Here is a sketch for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADq1n.png)) If the FOV is 60° and the far plane distance is 1000. Then in my opinion the z-value should be equal to `![zOffset/farPlaneDist=cos(30°)](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cfrac%7BzOffset%7D%7BfarPlaneDistance%7D%20%3D%20cos%2830%B0%29%20%5CLeftrightarrow%20zOffset%20%3D%20farPlaneDistance%20%5Ccdot%20cos%2830%29)` (I'm not allowed to post links, sry. Maybe someone could edit the post and get rid of the " ` " so that it's a link and not a code block. Thanks!)

   If you calculate it you will get `zOffset = 866`. This's around 300 units smaller then the value I get with the program.

**Question:**

What am I doing wrong when calculating the points? The basic form is the same, but the points still differ from what they should be. Do I have a mistake somewhere? If you need more information please say so, then I will provide it.

Comment: "Coordinate system: +x to the right, +z up and +z out of the screen" You may want to change the first "+z" into (presumably) "+y", if that is what you mean.

Comment: Thanks, edited it!